# I can not seem to get a 100% width background color after Position: Absolute on my code?

Tags: css, background, css-position

```
.left-side p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 95%;
  width: 100%;
background-color:black 
}
```

am trying to add a background color but doesn't span 100% on the page. Why? How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Please give us more of the HTML and CSS. We don't know at the moment how you have set the width of that p element's parent, nor can we see where it will be positioned in relation to the viewport and/or parent elements - what is the left: 50% relative to for example.

Comment: https://github.com/Okumu87/Sign-Up-Form.git  - check out the Github repo -- the name Halie West am trying to make the background black with 100% width horizontally

Comment: Please put code into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove property left and property top and add position relative to its parent container.

```
 .left-side p {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        width:100%;
    }
```

And HTML Code

```
<div class="left-side" style="position: relative;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```